# Netbeans cursor/breakpoints on wrong line

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans cursor/breakpoints are on the "wrong" lines. By single-stepping over lines, and monitoring variables in the watch window, I can see that it is executing the instruction 3 lines ahead, not the line I just stepped over.

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 7, trying to develop/debug a PHP/Javascript/MySQL website. I'm slightly beyond beginner level.

Everything was perfect until about a week ago. Then...

First: Netbeans no longer opened with panes and files set up in the IDE the same as when I closed it. Instead of opening the JS folder and file I was working on most recently it opens the PHP folder & file I was working on a week ago. Annoying, but not a show-stopper. Is there a .ini file in the appdata or registry I can delete or reset to change this?

Secondly the show-stopper: When I try to debug a javascript file the cursor and breakpoints are on the wrong lines - about 3 lines wrong. Very difficult to use at all - half the time the breakpoints end up on comments.

Is there a way to reset a project, or Netbeans itself, to clear these internal inconsistencies and confusion? Shutting & re-opening, rebooting the PC etc. don't work. Re-installing Netbeans is a last resort, would like to fix the current install.
Thanks in advance, Rob.

Edit: More info - it is somehow not saving changes I make in a JS file.
If I add lines of code, they are there in the source in the IDE. They are there in the file itself, when I open it through Windows outside of Netbeans. But the Netbeans debugger is not seeing the changes, but still using an "old" version of the file (which doesn't seem to exist as a file - might be in a cache somewhere?). This is even more evident when I change the name of variables - the "old" names of the variables appear as I single-step through, the "new" names of the variables never appear.
Weird stuff.

Further edit: deleted the Netbeans cache: \Users\MyName\Appdata\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2 as per this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans
No change: still uses "old" variables and code, doesn't recognise changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was the browser not downloading the edited JS file, but using a cached version.
Cleared Chrome's cache, went into "developer mode -> network" and set the "disable cache" radio button, and now the JS can be debugged.

Still annoying that Netbeans opens with a long-finished PHP file.